# Binding 2 windows together for alt+tab usage

Tags: windows-7

My basic developing workflow consists of a text editor and a command prompt. These are almost always used in tandem, side-by-side. So, to me they are essentially one window. An annoyance that I have is that when I hit alt-tab to go the browser (from my previously described set up) then alt-tab to go back, only the window that was being used when I went to the browser appears. Is there anyway to bind the windows of the text editor and the command prompt together for intuitive alt-tab usage? Thanks.

Comment: You could look out for 3rd party tools that can produce an manage virtual desktops for windows 7. This may help you.